# Html.BeginForm inside partial changes attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview, html.beginform

In my ASP.NET MVC (5.2) project, I have a page called `register.cshtml`. It doesn't include any forms or anything, just plain divs.

Inside one of the divs, I'm rendering a partial:

`@Html.Partial("~/Views/Users/_x.cshtml")`.

Inside `_x.cshtml` I have a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("/users/x"))
{
   ...
}
```

When I go to my register page, I expect my form to be rendered as:

`<form action="/users/x" method="post"> ... </form>`

But instead, I'm getting this:

`<form action="/users/register?Length=23" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"> ... </form>`

What is `length=23`, why is there a `novalidate` attribute added, and why is it posting to an incorrect path?

Why is my form not rendering properly?

Comment: You are calling [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.Object%29). I assume it's not what you wanted. You're supposed to use controller/action names in `BeginForm`, not a url.

Comment: Assuming you have a controller named `usersController` with a method named `x`, then it needs to be `@using (Html.BeginForm("x", "users")) {`

Comment: Oh, how did I make such a simple mistake. yeah, corrected it now. could you please post it as an answer @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your wanting to post to a method named `x` in `usersController`, then it needs to be

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("x", "users"))
{
    ....
}
```

Note that your currently using the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.Object%29) that accepts `object routeValues` and because its a `string`, the method generated a route value for `Length` because that's the only property of `string` (the `/users/register` is because that the method that generated the main view)

Comment: See also update explaining the `Length` query string value

Comment: Yeah I also realized that it serializes all the properties of the object into query string parameters, which explains the mysterious length=23 :)

Answer (score 1):

From your code

```
Html.BeginForm("/users/x")
```

i understand that users your controller and x is a method. So you can do in this way-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("x", "users", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "YourFormID"}))
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller",new { QueryString = 1}, FormMethod.Post, null))
{

}
```

Note : its due to passing wrong parameter in beginform constructor .

and in ur VIEW

```
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_x.cshtml")
```